# Mailbox statistics on Exchange server 2010

Tags: exchange-server, usage-statistics

I have a folder on my mailbox (which is on Exchange Server 2010) that collects various kinds of failure alert mails. I am trying to do a statistical analysis on the folder's contents. Does Exchange Server provide any way to do this? What would be the best way to get such statistics?

Answer (score 0):

You can do all sort of statistics gathering with PowerShell on Exchange 2010.

For starters, take a look at [Get-MailboxFolderStatistics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996762.aspx)  and [Get-MailboxStatistics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124612.aspx).  There are a number of blog posts and technical articles available that give examples of the kind of analysis you're discussing.  [This article](http://www.n2networksolutions.com/2011/03/18/searching-exchange-2010-mailboxes-with-powershell/) gives a couple of one-line script examples.